# What is wrong with my swift code?

Tags: ios, swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        questionLabel.text = questions[currentQuestionIndex]
    }
}
var questionLabel : UILabel!
var answerLabel: UILabel!

    let questions:  [String] = [
    "What is 7+7?",
    "What is the capital of Vermont?",
    "What is cognac made from?",
    ]
    let answers: [String] = [
    "14",
    "Montpelier",
    "Grapes",
]
    var currentQuestionIndex: Int=0
...
func showNextQuestion(_ sender: UIButton) {
    currentQuestionIndex+=1
    if currentQuestionIndex == questions.count  {
            currentQuestionIndex = 0
        }

        let question:  String = questions[currentQuestionIndex]
        questionLabel.text = question
        answerLabel.text = "???"
}

func showAnswer(_ sender: UIButton)  {
        let answer: String = answers[currentQuestionIndex]
        answerLabel.text = answer
}
```

The code will not build. Whenever I try to add "IBAction" in front of the func it says it needs to be replaced. The func is underlined and the error is " Expected Expression after operator." The error is next the func showNextQuestion line. Please and thank you

Comment: Perhaps you should be putting the functions and variable inside the class instead of outside.

Comment: That didn’t work. More errors showed up

Comment: That's because you are creating UILabel objects without wiring them.  Either make them optional or wire them.

Comment: Update your question with your updated code (inside the class where it belongs) and include relevant error messages and point out the lines causing the errors. But first make some attempt to search on the errors and fix them yourself first.

Comment: I think you should try read some project example/tutorial...

Answer (score 0):

Please Check Below Class Created Using Your Functions

Class 1 : ViewController

Class 2 : NewController With Extensions

```
import UIKit

/// Option 1
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    /*
     /// Add IBOutlets Here

    */

    /// Your Assigned Properties
    private var questionLabel : UILabel!
    private var answerLabel: UILabel!
    private var currentQuestionIndex: Int = 0

    let questions:  [String] = [
        "What is 7+7?",
        "What is the capital of Vermont?",
        "What is cognac made from?",
        ]

    let answers: [String] = [
        "14",
        "Montpelier",
        "Grapes",
        ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        /// Assign Question To Label
        questionLabel.text = questions[currentQuestionIndex]
    }

    /// Take These Functions Inside Your Class
    func showNextQuestion(_ sender: UIButton) {
        currentQuestionIndex+=1
        if currentQuestionIndex == questions.count  {
            currentQuestionIndex = 0
        }

        let question:  String = questions[currentQuestionIndex]
        questionLabel.text = question
        answerLabel.text = "???"
    }

    func showAnswer(_ sender: UIButton)  {
        let answer: String = answers[currentQuestionIndex]
        answerLabel.text = answer
    }
}

/// Option 2
class NewController: UIViewController
{
    /*
     /// Add IBOutlets Here

     */

    /// Your Assigned Properties
    private var questionLabel : UILabel!
    private var answerLabel: UILabel!
    private var currentQuestionIndex: Int = 0

    let questions:  [String] = [
        "What is 7+7?",
        "What is the capital of Vermont?",
        "What is cognac made from?",
        ]

    let answers: [String] = [
        "14",
        "Montpelier",
        "Grapes",
        ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        /// Assign Question To Label
        questionLabel.text = questions[currentQuestionIndex]
    }
}

//MARK:- Required Functions
extension NewController {

    /// Or Make Separate Extension of Class and Add Functions there
    func showNextQuestion(_ sender: UIButton) {
        currentQuestionIndex+=1
        if currentQuestionIndex == questions.count  {
            currentQuestionIndex = 0
        }

        let question:  String = questions[currentQuestionIndex]
        questionLabel.text = question
        answerLabel.text = "???"
    }

    func showAnswer(_ sender: UIButton)  {
        let answer: String = answers[currentQuestionIndex]
        answerLabel.text = answer
    }
}
```

**Mistake you did** You Have Declared functions outside the class

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        questionLabel.text = questions[currentQuestionIndex]
    }
}
/// Here - This is Wrong
```

**Right Method**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        questionLabel.text = questions[currentQuestionIndex]
    }

    /// Functions Need to Be Here
}
```